# Dimensionality of Grassmann numbers

Tags: special-relativity, supersymmetry, dimensional-analysis, grassmann-numbers

I have noticed in a few texts ( Introduction to Supersymmetry by Harald J. W. Muller-Kirsten, Armin Wiedemann for instance) state that Grassmann variables that are used in superfields have dimension $\pm \frac{1}{2}$ and doesn't explain where they got it from just that is. Could somebody explain why please?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It can e.g. be seen from the formula for the covariant derivatives $D$ in superspace that the Grassmann variables $\theta$ must have half the dimension of the spacetime coordinates $x$.